# What does “Tartuffism” mean?

Tags: ethics

In the book of Nietzsche called "On the Genealogy of Morals" there is this sentence:

> Let us speak out this new demand: we need a critique of moral values, the value of these values is for the first time to be called into question—and for this purpose a knowledge is necessary of the conditions and circumstances out of which these values grew, and under which they experienced their evolution and their distortion (morality as a result, as a symptom, as a mask, as Tartuffism, as disease, as a misunderstanding; but also morality as a cause, as a remedy, as a stimulant, as a fetter, as a drug), especially as such a knowledge has neither existed up to the present time nor is even now generally desired.

So, does anyone know what "Tartuffism" mean? Searching over the internet didn't give anything satisfactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote is from the preface, chapter 6, of *On the Genealogy of Morality: A Polemic.* When Nietzsche characterizes moral as *Tartuffism* he means bigotry, alluding to the leading character from Moliere's play with the same title.

Answer (score 2):

See [Tartuffe, or The Impostor, or The Hypocrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartuffe) by [Molière](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moli%C3%A8re).

Thus : *Hypocrisy*.